# What is the max current for the EV3 I/O port's VCC pin (pin 4)?

Tags: ev3, electronics

The LEGO EV3 [Hardware developer kit](https://education.lego.com/v3/assets/blt293eea581807678a/blt471320cb14ed0291/5f880386631d5a2165df4144/lego-mindstorms-ev3-hardware-developer-kit.zip) says that the fourth pin of input or output port provides a voltage of 5 volts but doesn't give the the maximum current that can be drawn from the pin.

What is the max current that can be drained from the VCC pin (pin 4 at 5V)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in the schematics, pin 4 of all of the input and output ports plus the 5V on the USB host port is connected to VCC5V/VCC5VIGEN, which is supplied by U23 (the analog/digital converter is also connected to this, but current draw for that is negligible). U23 is a [TPS2041BDBVR](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2041B) which limits the current to 1A and has a continuous current of 500mA.

So all ports and USB need to be considered at the same time and must not exceed 500mA on average or 1A peak.